# Property injection upon initializing object manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ninject.web.mvc

When using Ninject property injection the following works only if the object is instantiated by the framework (not by developer in code) so that the injection works:

```
public class SomeController: Controller {
   [Inject]
   public DbContext db {get; set;}

 ...
}
```

However when the object has to be instantiated in the code by the developer the binding does not happen (I don't wanna say fail because it does not happen).

```
public class DataProvision {
   [Inject]
   public DbContext db {get; set;}

   public List<T> GetList<T>() where T: class, new() {
       return db.Set<T>().toList();
   }
 ...
}

public class Test {
    public static void Test(){
        DataProvision dp = new DataProvision();
        var getValue = dp.GetList<Person>();
    }
}
```

Is it even supported by Ninject and if yes what is the solution.

Justification of why we are doing this: Switching between back-up databases and active DBs effortlessly in case emergency

Comment: That's why you should favor constructor injection over property injection. Property injection leads to [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) which is a design smell. The `DataProvision` should require the `DbContext` dependency in its constructor.

Comment: @Steven: It wouldn't make any difference because in that case you gotta pass in the object. Why? this DataProvision class is supposed to provide DropdownMenues in a generic way in MVC views (it is not used in another conroller). So we actually don't want the DbContext to be there in the constructor. However this problem is solved by getting the db out of the kernel to take advantage of the binding.

Comment: You should not let your view have any dependencies. Views should be dumb and the controller should pass on all the data the view requires.

Comment: @Steven: The architecture we are using is kind of special, the behavior is fully lose coupled from even controllers, let alone the view. There is no dependency. The DataProvision is a static class actually that fills up the DropDownMenu used in views on demand. It is not as you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The DI framework has no opportunity to inject anything if you `new` up your own instances. If your code has access to the DI bindings, set up a kernel and use it to instantiate your class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void Test(){
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new YourDiModule());
        DataProvision dp = kernel.Get<DataProvision>();
        var getValue = dp.GetList<Person>();
    }
}
```

Using the above strategy, you'll probably need to tweak your DI configuration a little so that your context gets disposed when you want it to. (Your web application is probably normally set up to dispose the context after each web request completes, and it doesn't look like your test code is set up to run in the same kind of environment.)

Otherwise, you'll need to manage the dependency injection by hand:

```
public class Test {
    public static void Test(){
        using (var context = new DbContext()) // or however you create contexts
        {
            DataProvision dp = new DataProvision();
            dp.db = context;
            var getValue = dp.GetList<Person>();
        }
    }
}
```